# C++ Merge Sorting Unexpected Output

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, dynamic-memory-allocation, mergesort

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>

using namespace std;

void insert_elements_in_array(int *arr, int size)
{
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        cout <<"Enter element "<<i<<": ";
        cin >> arr[i];
        cout << endl;    
    }
}

void display_elements_in_array(int *arr, int size)
{
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        cout << arr[i] <<"  ";
    }
}

void merge(int *arr, int l, int m, int r)
{
    int i = l;
    int j = m+1; 
    int k = 0;
    int *temp = new int[r-l+1];

    while(i <=m && j <= r)
    {
        if(arr[i]<=arr[j])
        {
            temp[k] = arr[i];
            i++;
            k++;
        }

        else
        {
            temp[k] = arr[j];
            j++;
            k++;
        }
    }

    while(i <= m)
    {
        temp[k] = arr[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }

    while(j <= r)
    {
        temp[k] = arr[j];
        j++;
        k++;
    }
    
    for(int p = l; p<=r; p++)
    {
        arr[p] = temp[p];
    }
}

void mergeSort(int *arr, int l, int r)
{
    if(l < r)
    {
        int m = (l+r)/2;
        mergeSort(arr, l, m);
        mergeSort(arr, m+1, r);
        merge(arr, l, m, r);
    }
    else
        return;
}


int main()
{
    int size; 
    cout <<"Enter the Size of Array: ";
    cin >> size;
    int *arr = new int[size];

    cout <<"Now Enter Elements to do Merge Sorting "<<endl;
    insert_elements_in_array(arr, size);

    cout <<"The Unsorted Array is: ";
    display_elements_in_array(arr, size);
    cout <<endl;

    mergeSort(arr, 0, size-1);

    cout << "The Sorted Array is: "<<endl;
    display_elements_in_array(arr, size);

    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to apply Merge Sort and It works dine with array input size 2...
But when the input size exceeds 2 it could not print Sorted Array.

I think the problem occurs here in the merge() function at last where we assign the temp array elements to the original array.
Here:-

```
for(int p = l; p<=r; p++)
    {
        arr[p] = temp[p];
    }
```

Why the Program is not Printing Sorted Array???? I have used Dynamic Memory Allocation so that array size could take user Input.

Here is the O/P of the Program:-

[image]

Comment: Fishy: `int *temp = new int[l-r+1];`. It would expect `int *temp = new int[r-l+1];`

Comment: Related, the final loop in `merge` doing this: `arr[p] = temp[p];` is broken from inception. That index range, `int p = l; p <= r; p++`,  works fro `arr`, not for `temp`. That should be `arr[p] = temp[p-l];`. Unrelated, you are leaking `temp` on every invoke of `merge`. Not good.

Comment: After `while(i <=m && j <= r)`, how, in your opinion, could be `(i <= m)` or `(j <= r)`?

Comment: Have you tried to [*debug*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) your program? For example trying to catch possible crashes in a debugger? Or use the debugger to step through your code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values to see what really happens?

Comment: And whenever you think "dynamic array" in the future, use `std::vector`. Don't do your own memory handling, especially since you seem to forget to `delete[]` the memory you allocate.

Comment: @Yunnosch still it is not working.....It now shows garbage value....

Comment: Did you [*read* my first comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71908004/c-merge-sorting-unexpected-output#comment127066561_71908004). That isn't a would-be-nice. It is a death knell  to undefined behavior unless you fix it.

Comment: @WhozCraig thank you man, for your fix and it works and thanks for putting your comment on notice...Now Will you please explain to me why temp[p-l] works??

Comment: @WhozCraig if you have any other better options to do merge sorting then please let me know here....Thanks dude

Comment: @RibhuSengupta Look how you sized the buffer for `temp`. It is sized to hold N elements, where N is `(r-l+1)`. Suppose `r` is 5 and `l` is 2. That means `(5-2+1)`, e.g. 4 elements, which makes sense, since there are 4 elements inclusive: in 2..5: eg. 2,3,4,5. But the elements in `temp` start at 0 and run through 3, so you need to account for that when copying back from `temp` into the target range in `arr`. Draw it up on paper and it will make sense. There are easier ways to do this, btw, some much easier and more efficient, particularly when the low-side of the partiiton 'finishes' first.

Comment: An example that uses pointer math and more efficient merging [here](https://godbolt.org/z/58b4Tv79K). This can be made far more efficient if you pre-allocate temp space for N elements, then pass that down the recursive chain, properly offset the same way `arr` is offset. It can make an enormous difference when you're not constantly allocating and deleting all those small segments. Anyway, I leave tat efficiency optimization to you. Best of luck.